# Is this Japanese sentence correct?

Tags: english-to-japanese

My friend and I are new to Japanese, and we are trying to make sentences.

We tried to translate this sentence to Japanese:

> I can't play tennis, but I can play the piano.

And this is our Japanese sentence:

> テニスができない、でもピアノを弾くことができます。
>   Tenisu ga dekinai, demo piano o hajikukoto ga dekimasu.

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Note that でも Can only be used as "but" at the **beginning** of a new sentence, so you would have to separate your example into two separate sentences.

Comment: Thanks, user3856370 – I've added your correction to my reply to make it more conspicuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one way to say that in Japanese, except that in this case the reading for 弾く should be ひく rather than はじく.

(Edit: Also, per user385630's comment, please note that since でも as "but" or "however" can only be used at the beginning of a sentence, you'd also need to correct that. You could do so by splitting this into two sentences or by rephrasing with が or けど. Sorry not to have caught that before!)